# Raycast: How to limit projected curves only to Target Geometry and omit gaps?

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves

After the raycast, I want only the curves to remain on the target geometry and not, as can be seen in the image below, that the curves in the gap area are still present and connected. **Which setting do you have to choose for the raycast so that the curves are only projected onto the target geometry?**

[image]

I have already tried to delete the curve segments that are not on the target geometry with *Delete Geometry* using a Boolean operation (Boolean Math > Not) and the *Is Hit Selection*. Which didn't work. In another attempt, I tried to convert the curves into a mesh via *Curve to Mesh* Node, then to build an intersect with Mesh Boolean. That was very computationally intensive and caused blender to crash... **Is there an effective workaround for this issue?**

[image]

Many thanks in advance for any assistance, support or helpful ideas!

Comment: Hello ! Not sure if you want them to not move or .. ? You can try a Delete geometry node, invert the Is Hit output from the raycast not with a boolean math set to Not and plug it into the selection input of the delete geometry node

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply @Gorgious! I want the white curves only to be projected onto the target geometry. Everything that is not on the mesh should be deleted completely... So in the area of the hole.

I have actually already tried the Delete Geometry Node combined with the Boolean NOT. Unfortunately, Bledner does not delete the curve sections in the area of the hole. It doesn't matter if I set point, edges or spline in the dropdown menu...

Maybe I have a misconception 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is based on Gorgious suggestion.

The origin of the object seems to be locked at World Origin, so if you connect the position to the ray direction, it gets weird (although I'm not entirely sure about this - maybe someone can explain?).

Anyway. I Resampled the curve to get more definition, converted it to a mesh, and used the Delete Geometry node (set as Edge for better results).

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Vagabonk!! That's exactly what I was looking for :)